# Method isBackgroundSet() gives errors and doesn't let me set Color

Tags: java, if-statement, background, jframe

I am writing a code where I need to check if the panel's color is set to Yellow and if it is, change the buttons color to another color. I am trying to do this but I keep getting an error.  Here is the code...

```
        if(panelMenu.isBackgroundSet(Color.YELLOW)) {
        goBackMainMenuOpt.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        exitButtonOpt.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

so here where it says ....isBackgroundSet(Color.YELLOW)) on that line Eclipse suggests me to remove the argument Color.YELLOW. Why is this a problem and is there another way to check the background color and change a button's color?

Comment: considering the API of `Component` there is no such method as `Component#isBackgroundSet(Color)` just one [without parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isBackgroundSet()), you might want to use [Component#getBackground](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground()) here and check if it´s yellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isBackgroundSet().
This function takes no parameters, returns a `boolean`.

The `getBackground` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground()) returns the color of the background, so you can check equality with `Color.YELLOW`

Comment: Yes the documentation helped for the isBackgroundSet(), thank you, but I still don't understand how I can check for the background color of the panel then change the button's color, I couldn't use the getBackground

Comment: `if(Color.YELLOW.equals(panelMenu.getBackground()))`